# Number of rows returned when adding before/after date logically inconsistant

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing information about a students visit to our tutoring center. Each time a student visits a record is produced which includes their names, their student number the date they visited, what they were there for and how long they were there.

We create new tables for each term

I was asked to get an unduplicated count of how many students were there during a certain term so I run the following.

```
SELECT * FROM `tutoringdata_201350` group by `anum`
```

`anum` being the students unique identification number, which returns 524 results out of 5525 total records. In theory that should be my unduplicated count.

I was then asked to get records before and after a certain date in that same table, so I run.

```
SELECT * FROM `tutoringdata_201350` WHERE `cDate` <= "09/30/2013" group by `anum`
```

Which works, so far as the date is concerned and no duplicate people are returned so far as I can see in the results window if I sort by the anumber they are all unique. BUT the total number of results returned is 375

So to get students after that date I run

```
SELECT * FROM `tutoringdata_201350` WHERE `cDate` > "09/30/2013" group by `anum`
```

which also appears to work, no duplicated students in the returned results but total number of returned results is 428.

375 + 428 is 803 not 524 which I would expect. I'm having trouble following the logic, which of the 2 different types of queries are producing an inaccurate number of results.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

You probably want something like this;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT anum) unique_students
  FROM `tutoringdata_201350`
 WHERE cDate <= 'whatever'
```

You could also do this to find out how many visits each student made.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) visits,
       anum
  FROM `tutoringdata_201350`
 WHERE cDate <= 'whatever'
 GROUP BY anum
```

You are also, I think, making a mistake in the way you are comparing dates.

MySQL uses an internal `DATE` and `DATETIME` format. If you want to compare such data items in your table to a text-string constant, you need to use the correct format -- YYYY-MM-DD -- for that string. For example:

```
WHERE cDate <= '2013-09-30'
```

The comparison in your example isn't correct.  **Edit**. If your dates are stored as text strings as `MM/DD/YYYY`, you need to use the following sort of comparison.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(cDate, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '2013-09-30'
```

This will convert your legacy date strings to `DATE` format. Then the comparison will work.  If you don't do this MySQL is just comparing strings to strings.  (You may, or may not, luck out if the years don't vary.)

Now, your counts of unique students before and after the first of October do not necessarily sum up to the count of unique students for the whole term. Here's an example.

```
Joe     Sept 28
Joe     Sept 29
Mary    Sept 30
Henry   Sept 30
Joe     Oct 1
Stephen Oct 1
```

Overall there are four distinct students. In Sept there are three. In October there are two. If you add those two numbers you get five. That's more because you're double-counting Joe by adding those two numbers.

Comment: The mistake with the date is a result of the application being ported from an old access database to a webbased php application a few years before I got here. The data was kept in the same format as the data from the access database so that it could all be lumped together and reported on. As a result the date is in MM/DD/YYYY format held in a text field. 

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `anum`) unique_students FROM `tutoringdata_201350`

Actually returns 524, which was my original count. Running your count for both directions produces 375 & 428 exactly as my originals above.